# How to create separate DrawingGroups in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, drawing, kinect

I want to create a WPF application in C# that shows skeletons from 2 different Kinects at the same time. For that I created an ArrayList to hold DrawingGroup objects for separate Kinects. When I try to add the DrawingImage into the image sources arraylist then it gives me the error about new DrawingImage(ImageGroup) having the wrong argument in it.

```
drawingGroups.Add(new DrawingGroup(););
imageSources.Add(new DrawingImage(drawingGroups[sensors-1]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said that you have an `ArrayList` of `DrawingGroup` objects. When you get elements of this collection by the indexer `[]` (in `drawingGroups[sensors-1]`), you just get an `object` instead of a `DrawingGroup`. You could cast the object to `DrawingGroup`, but it would be better to use a strongly typed collection like [`List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Just change the type of `drawingGroups` to `List<DrawingGroup>`:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
...

var drawingGroups = new List<DrawingGroup>();

drawingGroups.Add(new DrawingGroup());
imageSources.Add(new DrawingImage(drawingGroups[sensors-1]);
```